# Analytic subset that is a smooth submanifold

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $Y\subset X$ be a closed analytic subset that is an embedded smooth submanifold, then is $Y$ a complex submanifold of $X$?